# Remove a href from a specific domain not working

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to remove every `<td>` containing an specific domain but i wonder why the regex is not working

```
$html = preg_replace("@<td align=\"center\">(.*?)liversely(.*?)<\\/a><\\/td>@s", "", $html);
```

Here is how the html look like

```
<td align="center"><a href="http://liversely.com/lock?q=something" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://otherdomain.com/images/dlbutton10.png"></a></td>
```

I want to remove every instance of code shown above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `<\\/a>` regex pattern present within the `@` delimiters would match `<` then a `\` symbol, then a forward slash symbol `/` then `a>` . But there isn't a closing tag like this . So your pattern failed to match.

Changing your pattern like below will match the input string.

```
@<td align=\"center\">(.*?)liversely(.*?)</a></td>@s
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vX0rK0/1)